# Haskell Instance of Num [Char] required for definition of getPara error

Tags: haskell

```
getPara :: (Num [Char])  =>  [Char] -> Integer -> [Char]
getPara "" _ = ""


getPara str nr 
    | (nr == 0 ) && ((head str) == ')' ) = ')' : getPara "" 0 
    | ( nr == 0 ) && ( (head str) == '(' ) = '(' : (getPara (tail str) 0)
    | (nr /= 0 ) && ( (head str) == '(') = (getPara (tail str) nr-1) 
    | (nr == 0 ) && ( (head str) /= '(' ) = (head str) : (getPara (tail str) 0 )
    | otherwise = (getPara (tail str) nr)
```

What I am trying to do is to get from a String the nr set of brackets and the error I get is:

```
Illegal Haskell 98 class constraint in type declaration
*** Expression : getPara
*** Type       : Num [Char] => [Char] -> Integer -> [Char]
```

What is the problem?

Comment: What is that class constraint supposed to be good for? `[Char]` is a fixed type, either it's `Num` always (it shouldn't be) or never.

Comment: @leftaroundabout because you get an error message suggesting that maybe you need something like that, if you don't have that constraint:  `No instance for (Num [Char])
      arising from the literal `1' at ...`.  And maybe the OP thought that adding the constraint was the way to fix it.  But really the error is caused by missing parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your type signature for `getPara` is not allowed, but the underlying problem is that you're missing parentheses somewhere deep in the definition.  If your change your code to:

```
getPara :: [Char] -> Integer -> [Char]
getPara "" _ = ""

getPara str nr 
    | (nr == 0 ) && ((head str) == ')' )  = ')' : getPara "" 0 
    | (nr == 0 ) && ( (head str) == '(' ) = '(' : (getPara (tail str) 0)
    | (nr /= 0 ) && ( (head str) == '(')  = (getPara (tail str) (nr-1))  -- here!
    | (nr == 0 ) && ( (head str) /= '(' ) = (head str) : (getPara (tail str) 0 )
    | otherwise = (getPara (tail str) nr)
```

it compiles ... but I'm not sure if it works.

There were two changes:

1. type signature of `getPara`
2. surround `nr-1` in parentheses in

   ```
   | (nr /= 0 ) && ( (head str) == '(')  = (getPara (tail str) (nr-1))
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Matt's answer, let's beautify the code (I didn't check if it works, though). First of all pattern matching for lists is much nicer than lots of `head` and `tail`:

```
getPara :: [Char] -> Integer -> [Char]
getPara "" _ = ""
getPara (x:xs) nr 
    | (nr == 0 ) && ( x == ')' )  = ')' : getPara "" 0 
    | (nr == 0 ) && ( x == '(' ) = '(' : getPara xs 0
    | (nr /= 0 ) && ( x == '(' )  =  getPara xs (nr-1)  -- here!
    | (nr == 0 ) && ( x /= '(' ) = x : getPara xs 0 
    | otherwise = getPara xs nr
```

Now you can pattern match even more:

```
getPara :: [Char] -> Integer -> [Char]
getPara "" _ = ""
getPara (')':xs) 0                 = ')' : getPara "" 0 
getPara ('(':xs) 0                 = '(' : getPara xs 0
getPara ('(':xs) nr   | nr /= 0    = getPara xs (nr-1)  -- here!
getPara (x:xs) 0      | x /= '('   = x : getPara xs 0 
getPara (_:xs) nr                  = getPara xs nr
```

**[Edit]**

As Daniel pointed out, a careful analysis would reveal that the remaining guards are always true.

```
getPara :: [Char] -> Integer -> [Char]
getPara "" _ = ""
getPara (')':xs) 0   = ')' : getPara "" 0 
getPara ('(':xs) 0   = '(' : getPara xs 0
getPara ('(':xs) nr  = getPara xs (nr-1)  -- here!
getPara (x:xs) 0     = x : getPara xs 0 
getPara (_:xs) nr    = getPara xs nr
```

Comment: One further suggestion for the second version: both guards can be omitted.